# What does chome chome mean?

Tags: translation

In this anime they have a song that's called, *Omae no Tou-chan Chome-Chome*

So I looked what chome chome is, and they say
- It's an euphemism for sex
- It's an onomatopeia (related to sex)
- It's a whatever unprintable word

and nobody gives a clear answer that makes sense with the title of the song. What does chome chome mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

チョメチョメ is one of the ways of reading [the symbol(s) `××`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38517/5010) out loud, which is used to mask a word or a part of a word. I wonder if there is an English equivalent for this... If you know how to read the `**` part in "f**k" in isolation, that's it. If I understand correctly, it was originally a generic placeholder like まるまる or なになに, but later チョメチョメ gained a sexual connotation. チョメチョメ was a popular word in the 1980's, but it's almost outdated now. Teenagers may not even know this.

By the way, the [lyrics of the song](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-15271.html) explain the usage of this word very well :)

Related:

- [How do you pronounce "☓☓" as a placeholder?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12907/5010)

Answer (score 5):

JMDict defines it as follows:

> ｘｘ（reading: ちょめちょめ）
>
> - blankety-blank
> - bleep
> - used in place of sensitive word (often sexually related)

So one English translation of the song title is "Your Father is a *bleep*"

It's a placeholder for some bad words. The specific words are up to your imagination.

More online discussion on this song title:

- https://hinative.com/ja/questions/375614

Answer (score 3):

According to the site below, チョメチョメ is a slang used to pronounce redacted or censored words.
http://zokugo-dict.com/17ti/cyomecyome.htm

In Japanese printed censored words are usually represented as a series of ○ or × or ※ or＊.
In English they are replaced by a black rectangle or symbols like #$@&%*!, specially when they are profanities.
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/192928/meaning/m1u/伏字/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/192928/meaning/m1u/%E4%BC%8F%E5%AD%97/)

So the exact meaning of the word depends on the context.
It is some kind of unprintable word, and from the lyrics, it seems to be about sex.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's technically right, but my best guess would be that Otsu-chan's song translates to:  "Your father is a mother-f**ker", with part of that censored.